# Adding a join to a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, outer-join

I have a select statement. I need to add another join to this select statement. The join which I want to add to this select statement is at the bottom.. I tried it but getting an error

If I added it before where statement i am getting an error

Msg 4122, Level 16, State 1, Line 34
Remote table-valued function calls are not allowed.

```
SELECT   FactId
        ,UserType
        ,wr.WorkRequestId
        ,wr.XerisUserKey
        ,xu.CsuserUserID UserId
        ,u.fname UserFName
        ,u.lname UserLName
        ,b.PatientId
        ,p.firstname PatFName
        ,p.lastname PatLName
        ,GroupId
        ,HospiceGroupKey GroupKey
        ,WR.ContactKey
        ,C.ContactId
        ,C.FirstName
        ,C.LastName
        ,Convert(datetime,(Convert(varchar, SD.Date,101) + ' ' + ST.TimeOfDay ))  Start_dtm
        ,Convert(datetime,(Convert(varchar, CD.Date,101) + ' ' + CT.TimeOfDay ))  End_dtm
        ,DATEDIFF(s,Convert(datetime,(Convert(varchar, SD.Date,101) + ' ' +ST.TimeOfDay))
        ,Convert(datetime,(Convert(varchar, CD.Date,101) + ' ' + CT.TimeOfDay )))  WRDuration
        ,(Convert(Decimal(18,3), DATEDIFF(s,Convert(datetime,(Convert(varchar,  SD.Date,101) + ' ' + ST.TimeOfDay ))
        , Convert(datetime,(Convert(varchar, CD.Date,101) + ' '+ CT.TimeOfDay ))))) * 
                (Convert(Decimal(18,3),LineItemCount)/Convert(Decimal(18,3),PatientBucketItemCount)) Duration
        ,CallBackNumber
        ,WorkRequestType
        ,B.LineItemCount
        ,ArchiveLocation
        ,Processed
        ,ArchiveQueueType
        ,TQA
        ,Exclude
        ,CallId

FROM bi.dbo.FactWorkRequestTouches (NOlock) WR
INNER JOIN bi.dbo.BridgePatientWorkRequest B
ON B.WorkRequestId = WR.WorkRequestId
INNER JOIN bi.dbo.dimPatient (NOlock) P
ON B.PatientId = P.CphPatientID
INNER JOIN bi.dbo.DimXerisUsers (NOlock) XU
ON WR.XerisUserKey = XU.XerisUserKey
INNER JOIN cdc.dbo.csuser (NOlock) U
ON XU.CsuserUserID = u.user_id
INNER JOIN bi.dbo.DimTimeOfDay (NOlock) ST
ON WR.StartTimeOfDayKey = ST.TimeKey
INNER JOIN bi.dbo.DimTimeOfDay (NOlock) CT
ON WR.CompletedTimeOfDayKey = CT.TimeKey
INNER JOIN bi.dbo.DimDate (NOlock) SD
ON WR.StartDateKey = SD.DateKey
INNER JOIN bi.dbo.DimDate (NOlock) CD
ON WR.CompletedDateKey = CD.DateKey
LEFT OUTER JOIN bi.dbo.DimContact (Nolock) C
ON WR.ContactKey = C.ContactKey
WHERE CompletedDateKey = '20140131'
AND ArchiveQueueType = 0
AND PatientBucketItemCount <> 0
AND Exclude = 0
AND P.ENDDate is Null
```

This is the join I want to add to this select statement

```
   left outer join ssdba.excelleRx_WebFOCUS.dbo.DimHospiceHiearchy (nolock) h
     on b.groupid = h.group_id
```

Comment: Try  `left outer join ssdba.excelleRx_WebFOCUS.dbo.DimHospiceHiearchy as h with (nolock)
on b.groupid = h.group_id`

Comment: Its working Thankyou so much @Mihai.  Can you please help me with the store procedure for this select statement

Comment: `CREATE PROCEDURE ProcedureName AS your query;  GO`

Comment: I dont know about store procedures well. So if you can, please help me with this Storeproc @Mihai